# Переклад слова "применимый"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти "применимый" одним словом? "Застосовний"?

Comment: Так, такий варіант [є](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=32769&page=1054).

Comment: P.S.: Загалом, на цьому сайті (як і в усій мережі StackExchange) прийняті трішки інші правила оформлення запитань. Потрібно, щоб той, хто запитує, надав контекст (наприклад, для якого речення й ситуації це потрібно) і показав власні спроби знайти відповідь (наприклад, шукав у таких-то словниках — нема). У Вашому випадку — конче не вистачає пояснення, чому Ви сумніваєтеся у «застосовний» (Ви не певні, що таке слово існує, не певні, що воно всюди доречне, чи чому?).

Comment: дякую. Я був дещо спантеличений, бо укрвікі каже "Рідкісні в українській мові й дієприкметники на -мий, які досить поширені в російській мові." https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дієприкметник#Вживання_дієприкметників_в_українській_мові

Контексту немає, нажаль.

Comment: дякую за словник, але нажаль словник не вказує коли (за яких обставин) слово було вперше отримано. Бо у мене враження, що це новоутвір з наукової літератури, який було новоутворено саме для перекладу російського слова. Звісно, це суб'єктивне враження

Comment: Так _застосовний_ і не є дієприкметником (і навіть не закінчуєится на _-мий_); це суто прикметник. Це нормально — перекладати російський дієприкметник українським прикметником. Те, про що каже Вікіпедія (мовляв, такого в українській мові майже нема), — це, наприклад, _застосуємий._

Comment: А про час й обставини утворення слова в запитанні нічого й не було написано (тому я не міг здогадатися, що Вам це треба). Тому й рекомендують писати запитання більш розлого. Цілком може бути, що це новотвір для наукової мови. Перше трапляння, що я бачу, — «всі ці положення цілком застосовні і до Росії 1905 року» — в перекладі 1916 року книги Леніна 1905 року; друге — «всебічне вивчання природи матиме величезне застосовне економічне значіння» — з видання «Охорона пам'яток природи на Україні» 1927 року.

Comment: [Ось стаття](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162), про утворення подібних прикметників.

Comment: Якби ви свої думки з коментарів перенесли до запитання це б додало йому балів.

Comment: Пропоную уникати (напів-)відповідей у коментарях. Коментарі до запитання призначені лише для покращення/уточнення самого запитання, і більше ні для чого. Подібні діалоги можна виносити до чату, який саме для цього призначений.

Comment: виніс інформацію з коментарів у відповідь, всім дякую за співпрацю!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Застосовний" є правильним перекладом. Важливе уточнення - в російській мові це слово є *дієприкметником*, але при перекладі перетворюється на [*процесовий прикметник*](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162).

> ЗАСТОСО́ВНИЙ
>   , а, е.
>   Який можна застосувати, використати
>   . Це поміж людьми Цвичок дурний, а довідки із психушки у нього нема. Так що закон застосовний до нього, як і до будь-кого іншого
>   (М. Матіос)
>   ;
>   Метод застосовний для систем нелінійних алгебраїчних рівнянь, які описують сім'ю екстремалей
>   (з наук. літ.)
>   ;
>   Серед старозавiтних апокрифiв найбiльш розвинену фабулу мають апокрифiчнi казки про царя Соломона. Термiн “казка” цiлком застосовний до цих легенд
>   (з навч. літ.)
>   .

(з словника http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=32769&page=1054)

Не виключено, що цей переклад є відносно новим словом (перші згадки в науковій літературі з початку ХХ століття):

> «всі ці положення цілком застосовні і до Росії 1905 року» — в перекладі 1916 року книги Леніна 1905 року; друге — «всебічне вивчання природи матиме величезне застосовне економічне значіння» — з видання «Охорона пам'яток природи на Україні» 1927 року

(зі слів [@Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9?noredirect=1#comment8756_5680))